# How can Add Area in razor pages on dot net core 3.0/3.1?

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I want to add areas in core 3.1 in ***Razor Pages***, but Microsoft documents are for [asp dot net core 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1), and they want to create a [new report in January 2020](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/15895)!. Does somebody know how to add areas to the core 3.1?

I searched a lot on Google but couldn't find an answer.

in _AdminLayout :

```
...
        <a asp-area="Channel" asp-page="Index" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding"><i class="fad fa-cog"></i>&nbsp; تنظیمات آپارات</a>
        <a asp-page="Channel/Index" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding"><i class="fad fa-cog"></i>&nbsp; تنظیمات آپارات</a>
...
```

`asp-area="Channel" asp-page="Index"` not work and even don't create url when clicked on current page refresh, but `asp-page="Channel/Index"` work

and in Index (channel index)

```
@page "{area?}"
@model Aparat.Web.Areas.Channel.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    Layout = "_AdminLayout";
}

<h1>INDDDEX</h1>
```

Comment: did you try this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @moathnaji Yes, `app.UseMvc` it's  for 2.2 in core3 razor pages separate from MVC

Comment: Areas in Razor Pages 3.x are enabled by default. Just add a folder named Areas in the root of the project and work from there: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/areas#configuration

Comment: @MikeBrind not working for me. you can see images: [back-end](https://pasteboard.co/IJIuHJT.jpg),[back-end-2](https://pasteboard.co/IJIw1BG.jpg) , [front-end](https://pasteboard.co/IJItX02.jpg)

Comment: You should include the relevant code (not images) in your post and explain what you have done, how you expect it to work, and what happens instead.

Comment: @MikeBrind I edit the post

Comment: What's the first line of code in the _Index.cshtml_ page in your Channel area?

Comment: Remove the route template from the page. Just leave the `@page` directive.

Comment: @MikeBrind I update the post again and add index code.

Comment: @MikeBrind same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well when I add areas using below steps.

Create a **brand new** asp.net core 3.0/3.1 Web Application,in `Channel` area, right click `Pages` folder, select  Add -> New Item -> Razor Page and create `Index.cshtml`, you will get

[image]

Your `Index.cshtml` does not seems to be Razor Pages structure like mine from your provided picture.

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Areas.Channel.Pages.IndexModel

<h1>Hello from Channel Area</h1>
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Areas.Channel.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Test link:

```
<a asp-area="Channel" asp-page="Index">TestRedirect</a>
```

Comment: not working for me, I can't remember which update this file was made to separate .cs from HTML (2.2 or 3.0), I followed your steps (but still same problem)

Comment: I think Browser cached I press Ctrl + f5 after that area Working! But it needs more research.

Comment: Yes, I think the browser cached. Thank you guys for helping me.