# OnPost in Area with Razor page not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

(Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 - Razor Pages web application)

I am trying to trigger **OnPost** method which is in Areas >> Login >> Pages >> Index.cshtml.cs Razor Page. Somehow, it triggers **OnGet** method but when I try to post a form, it didn't trigger OnPost method.

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Areas.Login.Pages
{    
public class IndexModel : PageModel
        {
            public void OnGet()
            {
    //triggering
            }
            public void OnPost()
            {
    //not triggering
            }
        }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Areas.Login.Pages.IndexModel
@{
}

<form method="post">

    <input name="UserId" class="form-control" />        

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Note:
If I am not using Areas, OnGet and OnPost working fine.

I have tried below but none of them worked for me:

1. Tried https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/areas
2. [How can Add Area in razor pages on dot net core 3.0/3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177759/how-can-add-area-in-razor-pages-on-dot-net-core-3-0-3-1)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/324/areas-in-razor-pages): I have added the following code in Areas → Login → Pages

`_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@using WebApplication1
@namespace WebApplication1.Web.Areas.Login.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```