# Using fetch with OnPost (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I created an `ASP.NET Core Web App` and added an `OnPost()` method to `Index.cshtml.cs`.

```
              public void OnPost()
(breakpoint)  {

              }
```

I ran the project in debug mode putting a breakpoint onpost and opened `/` and typed `fetch('/', {method: 'POST'})` into the console. It gives me `net::ERR_ABORTED 400` and the breakpoint does not fire.

**EDIT:**

I uploaded the project folder: https://ufile.io/8z76xmdv

I have tried it on multiple computers but none work.

Comment: BTW,  This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533735/onpost-in-area-with-razor-page-not-working?rq=1 but as far as I can tell that is a different issue.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html As the default IIS Express binding used by your ASP.NET Core project expected a Host header of `localhost`, I doubt your way of calling `fetch` can reach the web app and kick out debugging.

Comment: @LexLi, `fetch` gives both the `origin` and `referer` headers. https://i.imgur.com/TORpA6X.png. So, I have no idea what the difference is but that is definitely the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately most web servers (not IIS alone) only check Host header https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host when routing incoming HTTP requests to web apps. You will find this header useful in more scenarios (like SNI).

Comment: @LexLi, why isn't the host header included in the chrome network request information?

Comment: You probably should try `fetch` with the full URL instead of just `/`.

Comment: @LexLi, I tried that. It had no effect. Is the `_RequestVerificationToken` by default needed? Also, I tried it using a GET request and the breakpoint was hit so it is very strange.

Comment: I tried to create the form using js but it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch` was the problem.

By default, an antiforgery token is required.

I just created a form on the page and I copied the `__RequestVerificationToken` from there to the request.

```
<form method=POST style="display:none"></form>
```

---

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('__RequestVerificationToken', document.querySelector('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').value);
// Add other fields
fetch('/', {method: 'POST', body: formData});
```

Now, I can use fetch just fine.

**Note:** do not set the `action` property in the html or the form will not contain the `__RequestVerificationToken` field.