# Razor pages route to a page in a different area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm struggling to route to a page in a different folder. it works fine if the page is in the same folder like so

```
(Url.Page("EditContact", new { area = "Admin", id="id" })
```

But if I move the "EditContact" page to a different area "Account" it tries to match `home/index`

```
https://localhost:/Account/Home/Index/_id_?page=%2FAccount%2FEditContact
```

However, I'd like it to route to

```
https://localhost:/Account/EditContact?id=2
```

Looks like the default route is being matched and not sure how to override it for this to work, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you modify Url.Page's area parameter after you have moved the page into account area folder?   According to your description, I have created a test demo on my side , it works well. I suggest you could post more details about how you check the url.page generate url and details folder makeup about your project.

Comment: Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177759/how-can-add-area-in-razor-pages-on-dot-net-core-3-0-3-1

Answer (score 1):

When generating route links to your pages, you must try to follow the way you have arranged the pages in your project. I'll illustrate using the following examples:

Let's say we have three pages: Index.cshtml, Todo.cshtml and Register.cshtml. Let the first and second page live in the 'Pages' folder and the third page live in the Identity area of your project. The arrangement is illustrated below:

Pages -> Index.cshtml

Pages -> Todo.cshtml

Areas -> Identity -> Pages -> Account -> Register.cshtml

If I want to generate a link to the Todo page from my index page, the code is:

```
Url.Page("./Todo.cshtml");
```

because both pages are in the same Pages directory, while to generate a link to the Register page, the code is:

```
Url.Page("/Account/Register", new { area = "Identity" });
```

The generated link would be: "/Todo" and "/Identity/Account/Register".
If you want to add the scheme, then you can write the code:

```
Url.Page("/Account/Register", null, new { area = "Identity" }, 
Request.Scheme);
```

This will result in: "https://localhost:<port number>/Identity/Account/Register". localhost:<port number> will be replaced with your domain name if the project is published appropriately.